# What does this Python code do (it's about functions and classes)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading some Python code and saw these lines and couldn't figure out what's happening.

Here's the code:

```
class Connection():
    (....)
       .
       .          
       .

def connect(name) -> Connection: ...
    (....)
    (....)
    (....)
```

Comment: Are you talking about the `-> Connection`, and the `name: str` parts? It's type specification or typing, which is supported by Python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: If you *are* talking about the type hints, note that they're not supported before Python 3.5, certainly not in 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

It's dummy code, it doesn't do anything, it just shows you what the setup and format is of functions and classes.

Answer (score 1):

The writer created a class called Connection. Then, they made a function called connect which, I presume, creates an instance of the Connection class and creates a connection to a  database, but it is a dummy function, so it doesn't currently do something until you program it to do that.

Comment: dummy code!!??   it's in the sqlite3 module

Comment: i just wanted to know about the " -> Connection ..." part .